# ODataActionFilter being called twice

Tags: breeze

This is my first attempt at using breeze.js so I probably have something setup incorrectly, but not sure what it is.

I am experiencing an error when executing a simple query.  I'm using EF 5.0 DB first in a VS2012 project.

An error has occurred.
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
System.ArgumentNullException

at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) at lambda_method(Closure , IQueryable ) at Breeze.WebApi.ODataActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(HttpResponseMessage response) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)

In an attempt to determine what I was doing incorrectly, I download the breeze server source code  and included the project in the solution so I could trace the error.  The error is occurring in the OnActionExecuted event in ODataActionFilter.cs.  The strange thing is that the function is called twice for the same query.  The function is first called with the query in the responseObject.  The 2nd time the event is called, the result of the query is in the responseObject.  This is no longer a iQueryable object which results in the error.  I cannot determine why the function is being called a 2nd time when it already has the correct result.

Has anyone seen this before and can tell point me in a direction to fix it?

thanks

Comment: I have seen that ... but it is useless to guess at the cause for you. I may be able to help if you offer a little more information. How did you arrive here? Did you start with the MVC 4 SPA template [could be trouble]? Or some other template? Which NuGet package did you install? Did you create your own model and controller? If so, what attribute(s) adorn the controller?

Comment: Ward.  I did not notice your response before I posted the answer below.  Even though I was able to resolve it without reading your response, your suggestion was right on the mark.  I was not using the necessary attribute on the api controller.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question.

The solution was that my api controller did not have the new BreezeController attribute applied to it.  This is not in any of the documentation.  I did, however, find it in the samples.

ie
from documentation: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller

```
[JsonFormatter, ODataActionFilter]
public class TodosController : ApiController {
```

but, the current sample has this:

```
[BreezeController]
public class TodosController : ApiController {
```

this corrects the problem, but it was hard to find.  It's also not entirely clear to me whether the new BreezeController attribute should be added to the original two attributes or if it entirely replaces them.